# CakePHP delete session on user leave

Tags: php, cakephp

How could I check if a user has left my login form? Not logging in but actually leaving it?

As I want to delete the Auth.redirect session if they choose not to login so that when they return later they are not taken to their previous session!

So essentially running this:

`$this->Session->delete('Auth.redirect');`

I'm thinking some kind of check in the AppController that knows when a user was referred from the login form and deletes the session auth.redirect???

Or better yet checking if the current page is the login form and if not then delete the session!!!

and for those that are interested, this is how my login method currently looks:

```
function login()
{
        if(!(empty($this->data)) && $this->Auth->user())
        {
            $back_to = $this->Session->read('back_to');

            $auth_redirect = $this->Session->read('Auth.redirect');

            if($auth_redirect)
            {
                $this->redirect($auth_redirect, null, true);
            }
            else if($back_to)
            {
                $this->redirect($back_to, null, true);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(), null, true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->write('back_to', $this->referer());
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @Ethan's answer is correct, you cannot know when a user has *left* your site. I think what you're trying to avoid is an extraordinarily narrow case: User enters your site, clicks on Login, leaves the page, comes back a while later to the login page, logs in and is then redirected to where they were before. Personally I'd be perfectly fine with this behavior and not many people will ever notice or care about it. Moreover, the `Auth.redirect` value doesn't stick around forever. The session will eventually expire, usually within a few hours, which makes this edge case even rarer.

Comment: What about checking if they are viewing the login form and if not then delete the session so it only ever exists on the login form and after a redirect and then if they change their mind it gets scrapped and the back_to session will be used instead. Could u help with that? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if($this->here != '/admin/login')
        {
            $this->Session->delete('Auth.redirect');
        }
```

or this:

```
if($this->here != Router::url(array('admin'=>true,'controller'=>'users','action'=>'login')))
            {
                $this->Session->delete('Auth.redirect');
            }
```

Comment: `$this->here != '/admin/login'` will easily break. `$this->here` contains the entire URL path, not just relative to the app root. I.e. it may contain `/apache/user/cake/myapp/admin/login` if you have installed your app in a subdirectory. Also, you should not post this as answer to your question (or is it?).

Comment: How could I compare it to a controller action then? could I do this: `$this->here != array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login')` ???

Comment: `$this->params['controller'] == $this->name && $this->params['action'] == $this->action`

Comment: where do I put the controller name and action name then? as I'm comparing to that controller and action exclusively!

Comment: any updates as I don't understand what `$this->name` and `$this-action` do as I'm not telling the app to look for the users controller or login action using those????

Comment: In the controller, `$this->name` refers to the current controller and `$this->action` refers to the current action. `$this->params['controller']` refers to the *requested* controller, the same goes for the action. Make of that what you will, since I'm not really sure in what context you want to use this anyway.

Comment: I want to check if the current controller the user is viewing is the users controller and login method. if NOT then delete that cookie, which is what my code above does but it checks the url rather than the controller/action. So I don't see how your code would do that as it doesn't contain the information about either the users controller or login action...

Comment: Well then, `if ($this->name == $this->Auth->loginAction['controller'] && $this->action == $this->Auth->loginAction['action'])`. You should compare it to the action defined in `$this->Auth`, otherwise you'll have to keep the two settings in sync manually. But, what use is it to unset that value on every page except the login page? That just means the value will never contain anything but perhaps the login page, which seems pretty pointless.

Comment: The reason I need to delete the session is because I don't want it used by the login form when the user leaves the login page as it's no longer needed and if the user returns it will send them to the original location and not a new location hence it needed to be deleted!

Comment: Also that code still doesn't work as it doesn't take into account the admin prefix on the action I presume.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with CakePHP but your question sounds a bit strange to me. You are talking about PHP, a server side scripting language. A PHP script gets executed only when a request comes in (please correct me if there is something I don't know yet).

So, when a user calls the login page, the script gets executed. Now think of the following: Just after the login page has been loaded, the user closes the browser-tab with the login page. This does not trigger a request, so there is no possibility to inform the server about that action.

Maybe CakePHP can do such magical things, but I think we are talking about stateless HTTP, so I can't imagine how to realize something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a timestamp to the session of when you have last received a request from the user. For example, in `AppController::beforeFilter`, just add `$this->Session->write('lastSeen', time())`. You can then check how much time elapsed between the last time the user opened any page, and discard the `Auth.redirect` value if that interval was too long.

That's basically the same as expiring the session, just in a more controlled fashion. If you want to count the time a user simply has your page displayed on his screen as "activity" as well, you can use some Javascript AJAX to keep sending requests to the server to signal *"I'm active!"*

That's all quite a lot of work for very little benefit though. HTTP is stateless and doesn't allow you to track the user easily, period. Actually tracking whether a user is "actively" watching your page or not incurs a huge overhead and in this case seems like misplaced effort for the extraordinarily narrow purpose you want to use it for.

Comment: I'd prefer to just delete the session if the current page isnt the login form. Can you help do that? Cheers

Comment: @Cameron That essentially means you can just turn off the AuthComponent's auto redirect feature.

Comment: I have turned it off! But I still use that session for sending users back to the locations they came from.